# find distinct values of a varchar column in an super-large MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sorting, unique, distinct

I want to find the distinct values of a varchar column in a super large MYSQL table(1 billion rows). 
 I have the follow solution:

```
1. select distinct(col_name) from mytable; 
2. export this column to a text file incrementally(select col_name from mytable where myid>x and myid<x+n), then use linux sort 
sort myfile.txt | uniq -u
```

The problem with the 1st way(even if the column is indexed) is that the query might crash during a long period of time and then you would need to start over.
I'm leaning toward the second way, is there any other faster way?

Comment: is your column indexed in the DB?

Comment: @Zak: yes it's indexed, but given the size, it would still be too slow to do distinct

Comment: if it's already indexed, getting the distinct values is a matter of getting the index keys.  This is almost certainly going to be faster than the unix method

Comment: @spinning_plate: I edit the post for additional concerns and corrections.

Answer (score 1):

1. ...
2. ...
3. `SELECT col_name FROM mytable GROUP BY col_name;`

Even if they return the same result set, the two queries actually use different execution plans, and I noticed `GROUP BY` being somewhat faster than `DISTINCT` in MySQL, in some cases.

I support spinning_plate's comment regarding the index. If you already have one, it should be much less pain to get your result. What's the cardinality of your index?

Comment: Morel: cardinality is low relative to the size of the table.

Comment: A good thing then. What about a try, is it on a busy production server?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I've had to resort to this sort of nonsense before with MySQL as well.  If you can't just pull the index, and the GROUP BY doesn't work faster (not sure why this would be, going of @Ben..'s post), you could try segmenting the problem to batch it.

I would still work in MySQL, it's likely going to be faster than anything you write yourself or do on the UNIX command line.  Treat it like you would an materialized view or aggregation table in a DW -  One simple way would be to create a batch script that did SELECT DISTINCTS over small ranges into a second table with only distinct values (via MERGE or some other mechanism).  This is more batchable, but you run in to the same performance issues, just spread across jobs.  You'll have to experiment with the parameters (batch size).  If you're running this in a production environment and folks are expecting to get all distinct values as if they were querying direct to the DB, it would be best to have 3 tables, the original, a temporary one for the current batch, and a live table with the latest values and a date_modified column.

Comment: parallel processing and merge seems to be an interesting suggestion. at each batch you can reduce the input size, but you have to keep merging it,  would it be any faster than just one process in this case?

Comment: I have to agree that I cannot find any serious study confirming my experience. Might really depend on the query and the data.

Comment: @user775187 - nope. I've had to do similar things because the queries would time out - I was responding mainly to the comment in the main question